# WSO2 IS compatibility with MySQL InnoDB?

Tags: database, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to check if WSO2 Identity Servers is incompatible with MySQL InnoDB ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, WSO2 products are compatible with MYSQL. YOU can find tested database here,

https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Tested+DBMSs

Answer (score 0):

Inside the product `<product_home>`/dbscripts/ you will find different kind of DB scripts. There you will find mysql.sql for MySQL. INNODB is the default storage engine for MySQL where you can find ENGINE INNODB in side the script itself.